# In R, using data.table, is there a way see if a string value is in other columns in the same row?

Tags: r, data.table

I asked the following question of ChatGPT and Bing AI:

> can you write me R code using data.table to check if column value is in other columns, row by row

Which gave me something like the following MWE, where I added the "A"s to `col3`.

```
# Create sample data
dt <- data.table(
  id = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
  col1 = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
  col2 = c("E", "F", "G", "H"),
  col3 = c("A", "J", "A", "L")
)
cols_to_search<- c("col2", "col3")

# Define the function to check if a column value is in other columns within each row
dt[, check := ifelse(get("col1") %in% .SD, 1, 0), .SDcols = cols_to_search]

dt

> dt
   id col1 col2 col3 check
1:  1    A    E    A     0
2:  2    B    F    J     0
3:  3    C    G    A     0
4:  4    D    H    L     0
```

Another prompt gave me this as an output ... that is, it takes "A" from `col1` and searches all of `col2` and `col3` ... since it found "A" somewhere (anywhere) in `col3` , that row gets a `1`.

```
> dt
   id col1 col2 col3 check
1:  1    A    E    I     1
2:  2    B    F    J     0
3:  3    C    G    A     0
4:  4    D    H    L     0
```

**But I want something that returns the following:**

```
> dt
   id col1 col2 col3 check
1:  1    A    E    A     1
2:  2    B    F    J     0
3:  3    C    G    A     0
4:  4    D    H    B     0
```

Help?

Comment: If you look to the right side column above, you'll see that Chat* questions are banned. When you explained to Chat* that the output wasn't what you wanted, what it it say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use elementwise operator (`==`) instead of `%in%` (which returns `TRUE` if there is any value that matches the whole column) and `Reduce` it to a single logical vector with `|` (i.e. any TRUE in the corresponding rows) and coerce it to binary with `+`

```
dt[, check := +(Reduce(`|`, lapply(.SD, \(x) col1 == x))),
    .SDcols = cols_to_search]
```

-output

```
> dt
   id col1 col2 col3 check
1:  1    A    E    A     1
2:  2    B    F    J     0
3:  3    C    G    A     0
4:  4    D    H    L     0
```

---

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
dt %>%
   mutate(check = +(if_any(all_of(cols_to_search), ~ col1 == .x)))
```

-output

```
    id col1 col2 col3 check
1:  1    A    E    A     1
2:  2    B    F    J     0
3:  3    C    G    A     0
4:  4    D    H    L     0
```

Comment: This seems close, but not quite right. If I feed dt as:
dt <- data.table(
  id = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
  col1 = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
  col2 = c("E", "F", "G", "H"),
  col3 = c("I", "J", "A", "L")
)
... then this approach still returns a 1 in row 1.

Comment: @Ren what is the expected for that

Comment: @Ren The function does exactly what you described in the post i.e. checks for each row to find if there is a match, ,return 1 or else 0

Comment: I only want to search one row. Search each row by row, not searching the whole column

Comment: @Ren you need `==` instead of `%in%` as the former is elementwise.  Sorry, I thought you are using `%in%` to check for the whole column

Comment: @Ren With the update.  It gives for new data `dt$check
[1] 0 0 0 0`

Comment: That worked, thank you! I thought %in% was the right command, but I was overcomplicating it. Thank you!

Comment: @Ren isn't this already doing it